# Gauss-Jordan error de iteración en python

Tags: python, matriz

En cierta parte de mi código para resolver una matriz por el método de Gauss llego a este output:

La primera parte para reducir la parte inferior de la matriz está bien, pero durante la ejecución de la función para reducir la parte superior las iteraciones no llegan a toda la matriz ósea el código no llega a iterar hasta A[0][1] para reducir A[0].

```
1.000   0.333   0.000   0.000   |    1.251   
0.000   1.000   0.000   0.000   |    0.553   
0.000   0.000   1.000   0.000   |    -2.549  
0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000   |    2.047
```

Este es un ejemplo de lo que tiene mi codigo, llego a este punto donde la matriz A tiene estos valores, y luego empiezan las iteraciones de las otras columnas, pero falta algo para que las iteraciones recorran toda la matriz.

```
#Función para mostrar la matriz con espacios.
def mostrar():   
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for x in range(len(A[i])):
            if x != len(A[i])-1:
                print("{:.3f}".format(A[i][x]), end="\t")
            else: print("| \t {:.3f}".format(A[i][x]), end="\t")
        print(" ")
    print(" ")



#Matriz a trabajar.
A = [
    [1,     1/3,    2/4,    3/6,        1],
    [0,     1,      1/2,    23/32,      3/4],
    [0,     0,      1,      127/80,     7/10],
    [0,     0,      0,      1,          88/43]    
]

#Función para aplicar Gauss-Jordan a las columnas restantes.
def col2(i):
    verificador = i
    while verificador != -len(A)-1:
        #print("verificador:", verificador, "len(A):", len(A))
        pivote = A[verificador][i]
        print("Cambiar columnas.")
        print("")
        print("range:",range(len(A[i])))
        for x in range(len(A[i])):
            print("x:",x)
            print("{} - ( {} * {} ) = {}".format(A[verificador][x], pivote, A[i+1][x], A[verificador][x] - pivote * A[i+1][x]))
            A[verificador][x] = A[verificador][x] - pivote * A[i+1][x]
            mostrar()
        verificador -= 1


for i in range(-2, -len(A), -1):
    col2(i)

print("//////////////")
print("     END     ")
print("//////////////")
```

***[PREGUNTA]*** **¿Cómo puedo arreglas las iteraciones haciendo que pasen por toda la matriz?**

Cabe aclarar que para la solución de este caso no debo usar librerías o módulos.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Respuesta:**

Cambiar

`for i in range(-2, -len(A), -1):`

por:

`for i in range(-2, -len(A)-1, -1):`

- Gracias Sadan :)